# IEEE 802.3bt compliant PD with Low Power Consumption

Tags: ethernet, poe

I am designing a flow transmitter with Power over Ethernet(PoE) output. I am assuming the power consumption of the device is going to be low (< 11 Watts) for which power demand fall under 802.3at standard.

Now, the customer is demanding flow transmitter's supply designed to be compliant with 802.3bt (class 4, single signature) standard. I am well aware that PSEs are backward compatible.

My doubt is,
If I design transmitter's power supply 802.3bt compliant (which is for high power PDs) and if the total power consumption in run mode to be (let's say) 5 watts, will there be any problem in operation?

The reference design I am using https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slvub75a/slvub75a.pdf. which is based on TPS2372-4 interface IC.

If any further detail required to answer, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The PSE type and highest class defines the upper limit of its power supply, it's your choice.

See 802.3bt Clause 145.2.1 - a bt-compliant PSE is either type 3 or 4. It can be limited to any power class, from 1 through 8.
[image]

[image]

So, a 5 W PSE can only supply class 1 PDs.